# PERL - search for string in text, gets results with substrings as well

Tags: perl

I am searching in txt files, to find text that contain some characters, and move them in another folder...

I am searching for the following two keywords:

```
95-B/A
95-ASB/A
```

My code looks like that

1st EDIT : Put entire code

```
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;
my (%count,%countNegative,%countPositive,$i,$j,$key,@keys,@keysNegative,@keysPositive,$token,$tokenNegative,$tokenPositive,@tokens,@tokensNegative,@tokensPositive,$totalCount,$negativeCount,$positiveCount,$totalCountNegativeInText,$totalCountPositiveInText);



@files = <*.txt>;
foreach $fileToProcess (@files) {
open(INFILE,"<$fileToProcess") or die("cannot open file");
while (<INFILE>) { 
@tokens = &tokenize($_);
   foreach $token (@tokens) {
      if ($token =~ /[a-zA-Z]/) { 
         $count{$token} = $count{$token} ? $count{$token}+1 : 1;
      }
   }
}

@keys = keys %count;
@keys = sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } @keys;

for ($i=0;$i<=$#keys;$i++) { 
   if ((lc $keys[$i] eq lc '95-B/A') || (lc $keys[$i] eq lc '95-ASB/A')) {
   $oldlocation = $fileToProcess;
   $newlocation = '95BA';
   File::Copy::move($oldlocation, $newlocation);
   }
}

close(INFILE);
}
exit(0);


use strict;

my $true = 1;
my $false = 0;
my $text = "";
my $word;
# read text
while (<>) { $text .= $_; }
foreach $word (&tokenize($text)) {
   &printText(&rule3(&rule2(&rule1(&makeUnits(&cleanUp($word))))));
}
print "\n";
exit(0);

sub tokenize {
   $_ = $_[0];
   s/\s+/\n/g;
   s/^\n//;
   s/$/\n/;
   s/([.,!?:;,])\n/\n$1\n/g;
   s/\n(["'`])([^\n])/\n$1\n$2/g;
   s/([^\n])(["'`])\n/$1\n$2\n/g;
   s/([^\n])([.,])\n/$1\n$2\n/g;
   s/\n([A-Z])\n\./\n$1./g;
   s/\n\.\n([^"A-Z])/\.\n$1/g;
   s/(\.[A-Z]+)\n\.\n/$1.\n/g;
   s/([^\n])'s\n/$1\n's\n/g;
   s/([^\n])n't\n/$1\nn't\n/g;
   s/([^\n])'re\n/$1\n're\n/g;
   s/\n\$([^\n])/\n\$\n$1/g;
   s/([^\n])%\n/$1\n%\n/g;
   s/Mr\n\.\n/Mr.\n/g;
   return(split(/\n/,$_));
}

sub printText {
   my $i;
   for ($i=0;$i<@_;$i++) {
      print join('',reverse(split(//,&breakUnits($_[$i]))));
   }
   print " ";
}
```

It picks the ones who have 95-B/A
95-ASB/A, but it also picks those that have 95-B and 95-ASB (I don't want that, I want to pick ONLY the ones with 95-B/A and 95-ASB/A).

I suppose I am doing something wrong with handling the forward slash? Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

2nd EDIT : I think if I put the string check inside the loop where I find the tokens, it works fine.. Obviously I was messing the keys in the hash when I was doing the check in the next step, but I don't see the reason I shouldn't be doing it on the first step with the tokens.. What do you think?

```
@files = <*.txt>;
foreach $fileToProcess (@files) {
open(INFILE,"<$fileToProcess") or die("cannot open file");
while (<INFILE>) { 
@tokens = &tokenize($_);
   foreach $token (@tokens) {
      if ($token =~ /[a-zA-Z]/) { 
         if (($token eq '95-B/A') || ($token eq '95-ASB/A'))
         {
               $oldlocation = $fileToProcess;
   $newlocation = '95BA';
   File::Copy::move($oldlocation, $newlocation);
         }
         $count{$token} = $count{$token} ? $count{$token}+1 : 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://eval.in/216716

Comment: You need to show you *real* code. I am sure this isn't it, because `$oldlocation` and `$newlocation` don't change inside the loop and are independent of the hash keys. If this were real you would be moving the same files every time you happened to find a match in an arbitrary hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed unneeded parts of your code and modified it to be more readable. Now it's clear what the problem is: `%count` is almost global, but you need a new `%count` for each file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = glob '*.txt';

for my $fileToProcess (@files) {
    my %count;    #   <---- HERE. Declare %count in the loop.
    open my $IN, '<', $fileToProcess or die "Cannot open $fileToProcess: $!";
    while (<$IN>) {
        for my $token (tokenize($_)) {
            if ($token =~ /[a-zA-Z]/) {
                ++$count{$token};     # Ternary ? : not needed.
            }
        }
    }

    my @keys = sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count;

    for my $key (@keys) {
        if (lc $key eq lc '95-B/A' or lc $key eq lc '95-ASB/A') {
            print "move $fileToProcess because of $key.\n"
        }
    }
}

sub tokenize {
   $_ = $_[0];
   s/\s+/\n/g;
   s/^\n//;
   s/$/\n/;
   s/([.,!?:;,])\n/\n$1\n/g;
   s/\n(["'`])([^\n])/\n$1\n$2/g;
   s/([^\n])(["'`])\n/$1\n$2\n/g;
   s/([^\n])([.,])\n/$1\n$2\n/g;
   s/\n([A-Z])\n\./\n$1./g;
   s/\n\.\n([^"A-Z])/\.\n$1/g;
   s/(\.[A-Z]+)\n\.\n/$1.\n/g;
   s/([^\n])'s\n/$1\n's\n/g;
   s/([^\n])n't\n/$1\nn't\n/g;
   s/([^\n])'re\n/$1\n're\n/g;
   s/\n\$([^\n])/\n\$\n$1/g;
   s/([^\n])%\n/$1\n%\n/g;
   s/Mr\n\.\n/Mr.\n/g;
   return (split /\n/);
}
```

Comment: Check out my reply I put my entire code.. I don't put they keywords to search in the @keys as you do, as you can see if you look at my edited code ...

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks a lot for the solution ! So I was keeping the keys in the %count so every time after the 1st time the keywords were found, the keywords were still in the count so every file was passing through the filter, right ? If I make the comparison inside the token loop it is slower because the other method uses a hash which is faster?

Comment: @AdrFinance: Your explanation of the problem is correct. Comparison in the token loop shouldn't be slower if done correctly (it might even be faster because you can exit the loop early). If speed is a concern, you might also remove `sort` which server no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression pattern matching will match based on substrings. To avoid this, use `\b` to match 'word boundary'.

```
if (($keys[$i] =~ m/\b$tenka\b/) or ($keys[$i] =~ m/\b$tenksba\b/ )) {
```

Comment: This leads to a compilation error: Backslash found where operator expected at move10K1996.pl line 38, near "m/\b$tenka\b) or ($keys[$i] =~ m/\"
Backslash found where operator expected at move10K1996.pl line 38, near "$tenksba\"
 (Missing operator before \?). If I add a / after the first b it still gets the ones without /A...

Comment: Your explanation doesn't hold up. The regex `95-B/A` won't match a string with just `95-B`, with or without word boundaries.

Comment: Ok I edited my initial post and put my entire code, please take a look